# update no laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-update

boa tarde a todos!!!
eu montei o formulario , que vai enviar para o método "update" do laravel

```
public function update(Request $r, Voluntarios $vol)
  {   
      $up = $vol->update($r->all());
      var_dump($up);
  }
```

só que ele retorna falso, sem salvar...o que tá errado ???
to aprendendo ainda, e estou um pouco perdido ainda...
Obrigado a todos!!
Horácio

Answer (score 0):

Modifique o código como abaixo:

```
public function update(Request $r, Voluntarios $vol)
  {   
      $up = $vol->fill($r->all());
      $vol->save();
      var_dump($up);
  }
```